# Griffiths' Intro to QM -- Complex exponential solution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, complex-numbers

I have a question with Griffiths' approach to the infinite square well. (Please forgive me for my poor use of MathJax)

I was trying to find a way to solve the infinite square well using complex exponentials, but I found that no matter what I did, I would reach some kind of odd condition that couldn't be solved. Then I found this:

[How to solve infinite square well with exponential solution (of oscillatory type)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173246/)

The answer to this question uses Euler's formula to decompose the following and solving it.

$$e^{2ikL} = 1.$$

I am wondering if there is a way to solve this equation (or solve for the initial conditions in the infinite square well problem) without reference to Euler's formula.

Comment: You might well have a hard time in that $e^{ix}$ when drawn on an Argand diagram is a vector of unit length rotated by an amount dictated by $x$ and any expansion of $e^{ix}$ as a series leads to a splitting of the series into real and imaginary parts which relate to the cosine and sine function. I would have thought that Maths SE is the place to ask? https://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
\begin{align}
e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta
\end{align}
where $\theta$ is a real number.

Consider $e^{i \theta} = a + i b$ where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. We have
\begin{align}
\cos \theta + i \sin \theta = a + i b
\end{align}
We match the real part and imaginary part separately and obtain
\begin{align}
\cos \theta = a, \qquad \sin \theta  = b
\end{align}

Comment: I said explicitly without reference to Euler's formula.

Comment: @user2329239 the point is, it is 100% equivalent to write down:  $\psi = A + Bi$ where $A^{2} + B^{2} = 1$, and then go and solve for $A$ and $B$, and not use Euler's formula at all.  This answer shows that the two things are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

> $$e^{2ikL} = 1.$$

> I am wondering if there is a way to solve this equation (or solve for the initial conditions in the infinite square well problem) without reference to Euler's formula.

Yes. First note that
$$
1=e^{2\pi n i}\;,
$$
for any integer $n$.

Then take the natural log of both sides of your above-quoted equation to find:
$$
\ln(e^{2ikL}) = \ln(1) = \ln(e^{2\pi n i})\;.
$$
Or rather, since $\ln(e^{x}) = x$,:
$$
2ikL = 2\pi n i\;.
$$
Or rather:
$$
k = \frac{\pi n }{L}\;,
$$
for any integer $n$.